# How to draw backwards-bending line in chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I'd like to plot a backwards-bending line using chart.js.

For example: the equation `x=-(y-1)**2+1` should create this graph:
[image]

I'm using python and flask for my webpage. The code that generates the graph data inside the flask route looks like this:

```py
@bp.route('/chart', methods=('GET',))
def chart():
    y = np.linspace(0, 2, 10).tolist()
    x = [-(i-1)**2+1 for i in y]

    return render_template(
        'chart.html',
        x=x,
        y=y
    )
```

And my HTML file looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <meta id="x" data-x="{{ x }}">
    <meta id="y" data-y="{{ y }}">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
const x = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('x').getAttribute('data-x'));
const y = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('y').getAttribute('data-y'));

new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: x,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Backwards-Bending Line',
            data: y,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
})
</script>
```

This code creates the following graph:
[image]

You can see the x-axis increases and then decreases instead of wrapping the line backwards. How can I get the line to bend backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Chart.js` configuration, you should get rid of `data.labels` and instead define `datasets.data` as an `array` of objects, having an `x` and `y` property each.

A simplified result for your case would look as follows:

```js
new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Backwards-Bending Line',
            data: [
                {x: 0, y: 20}, 
                {x: 5, y: 15}, 
                {x: 8, y: 10}, 
                {x: 5, y: 5}, 
                {x: 0, y: 0}
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
            tension: 0.3
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="200"></canvas>
```

Please also consult [Data Structures > Object[]](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object) from the `Chart.js` documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Just one note, this only worked when I made all of the x values strings. To read this data in the Jinja template, I used `const data = JSON.parse('{{ data|tojson }}');`. You have to use the 'tojson' filter to escape the HTML encoding.

Comment: `x` values do not have to be strings if you define `options.scales.x.type: 'linear'`.